# Program breaks from switch java

Tags: java

for some reason, when I enter '1' on the switch menu, nothing happens, but the program doesn't terminate. It's the same with options 2-5. The default option works just fine. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ConversionTrial {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double pound;
    double euro;
    double dollars;
    double yen;
    double rupees;
    double poundEuro;
    double poundDollars;
    double poundYen;
    double poundRupees;
    int choice;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner exchange = new Scanner(System.in);

    menu: while(true) { 
        System.out.println("Please choose an option:");
        System.out.println("1.  Enter values");
        System.out.println("2.  Euros (1GBP = 1.28EUR)");
        System.out.println("3.  Dollars (1GBP = 1.51USD)");
        System.out.println("4.  Yen (1GBP = 179.80JPY)");
        System.out.println("5.  Rupees (1GBP = 95.60INR)");
        System.out.println("6.  Exit");

        choice = input.nextInt();

        switch(choice){
            case -1:
            case 6:
                break menu;
            case 1:
                    pound = exchange.nextDouble();  
                    System.out.print("Please enter your values you would like to exchange:");
                break;
            case 2:
                pound = exchange.nextDouble();
                euro = 1.28;
                poundEuro = pound * euro; 
                System.out.println("Your amounts in Euros are" + poundEuro);
            case 3:
                pound = exchange.nextDouble();
                dollars = 1.51;
                poundDollars = pound * dollars; 
                System.out.println("Your amounts in Dollars are" + poundDollars);
            case 4:
                pound = exchange.nextDouble();
                yen = 1.28;
                poundYen = pound * yen; 
                System.out.println("Your amounts in Yen are" + poundYen);
            case 5:
                pound = exchange.nextDouble();
                rupees = 1.28;
                poundRupees = pound * rupees; 
                System.out.println("Your amounts in Rupees are" + poundRupees);
            default:
                System.out.println("You must enter an option between 1 and 6!");

        }
    }
    input.close();
    exchange.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Probably because you call `nextDouble`, so it's waiting for a double?

Comment: Don't create two scanners on System.in - just create one and use it everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

First, don't create two scanner objects. Just create the one, and use that.

Second, in you options 1-5, you are waiting for input before outputting anything to the user, so that is likely why it seems to not be working. You should add a prompt for the value expected.

Third, you are missing `break;` at the end of cases 2-5.

Fourth, using a label is generally not the best way to do things. It can end up with some hard to read code. A better way would be to do it would be to have a flag variable, `boolean exit = false;`. Then, your while loop will loop based on it not being true, `while(!exit)`. And in your `case 6:`, `exit = true;`

Fifth, why do you have -1 exit, when it isn't an option given the user? I would remove that.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ConversionTrial{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double pound;
        double euro;
        double dollars;
        double yen;
        double rupees;
        double poundEuro;
        double poundDollars;
        double poundYen;
        double poundRupees;
        int choice;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        boolean exit = false;

        while(!exit) { 
            System.out.println("Please choose an option:");
            System.out.println("1.  Enter values");
            System.out.println("2.  Euros (1GBP = 1.28EUR)");
            System.out.println("3.  Dollars (1GBP = 1.51USD)");
            System.out.println("4.  Yen (1GBP = 179.80JPY)");
            System.out.println("5.  Rupees (1GBP = 95.60INR)");
            System.out.println("6.  Exit");

            choice = input.nextInt();

            switch(choice){
                case 6:
                    exit = true;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    System.out.print("Please enter your values you would like to exchange: ");
                    pound = input.nextDouble();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.print("Please enter your values you would like to exchange: ");
                    pound = input.nextDouble();
                    euro = 1.28;
                    poundEuro = pound * euro; 
                    System.out.println("Your amounts in Euros are " + poundEuro);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.print("Please enter your values you would like to exchange: ");
                    pound = input.nextDouble();
                    dollars = 1.51;
                    poundDollars = pound * dollars; 
                    System.out.println("Your amounts in Dollars are " + poundDollars);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.print("Please enter your values you would like to exchange: ");
                    pound = input.nextDouble();
                    yen = 1.28;
                    poundYen = pound * yen; 
                    System.out.println("Your amounts in Yen are " + poundYen);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.print("Please enter your values you would like to exchange: ");
                    pound = input.nextDouble();
                    rupees = 1.28;
                    poundRupees = pound * rupees; 
                    System.out.println("Your amounts in Rupees are " + poundRupees);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("You must enter an option between 1 and 6!");
                    break;
            }
        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Edit: As a bonus, I also noticed that option 1 doesn't actually do anything. Is that intentional? And for cleaner code, I would initialize the values of your conversion variables when you define the variables, instead of each time they are used. You could also use those values in your menu, so they only need to be changed once if the values change.

Answer (score 1):

The `menu` label is'nt really necessary. Get rid of it, that is bad code smell.

Additionally you miss the `break;` in all other cases.

Answer (score 0):

Add breaks for every case to exit the switch statement. Not sure if this is the answer you wanted, so let me know if you are looking for something else.

Answer (score 0):

It's like PeterMmm said. You forget the `break;` in your cases.
Your code is working but i think it does not what u want it to do.
If i press 1 i can type in a double and afterwards it tells me i can type in a value.
But with this value from switch 1 happens just nothing.
The other options i can type in a double and get the exchange in a foreign currency.

What are u planning to do?

Answer (score 0):

just ran your code and I have figured out what you want to do. I am getting the following:

```
> Please enter your values you would like to exchange:Please choose an
> option:
> 1.  Enter values
> 2.  Euros (1GBP = 1.28EUR)
> 3.  Dollars (1GBP = 1.51USD)
> 4.  Yen (1GBP = 179.80JPY)
> 5.  Rupees (1GBP = 95.60INR)
> 6.  Exit 2
> 1.2 Your amounts in Euros are1.536
```

But pay attention that you must enter double values.
Also, I insist that you use break to exit the switch for every case existing in your switch.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

When you select an option 1-5, the program then waits for another double (the amount you want to convert), only then does it respond. So select an option, then give it another double value and it should tell you the conversion amount

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ConversionTrial {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double pound;
    double euro;
    double dollars;
    double yen;
    double rupees;
    double poundEuro;
    double poundDollars;
    double poundYen;
    double poundRupees;
    int choice;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner exchange = new Scanner(System.in);

    menu: while(true) { 
        System.out.println("Please choose an option:");
        System.out.println("1.  Enter values");
        System.out.println("2.  Euros (1GBP = 1.28EUR)");
        System.out.println("3.  Dollars (1GBP = 1.51USD)");
        System.out.println("4.  Yen (1GBP = 179.80JPY)");
        System.out.println("5.  Rupees (1GBP = 95.60INR)");
        System.out.println("6.  Exit");

        choice = input.nextInt();

        switch(choice){
            case 1:
                pound = exchange.nextDouble(); 
                System.out.print("Please enter your values you would like to exchange:");
                break;
            case 2:
                pound = exchange.nextDouble();
                euro = 1.28;
                poundEuro = pound * euro; 
                System.out.println("Your amounts in Euros are" + poundEuro);
                break;
            case 3:
                pound = exchange.nextDouble();
                dollars = 1.51;
                poundDollars = pound * dollars; 
                System.out.println("Your amounts in Dollars are" + poundDollars);
                break;
            case 4:
                pound = exchange.nextDouble();
                yen = 1.28;
                poundYen = pound * yen; 
                System.out.println("Your amounts in Yen are" + poundYen);
                break;
            case 5:
                pound = exchange.nextDouble();
                rupees = 1.28;
                poundRupees = pound * rupees; 
                System.out.println("Your amounts in Rupees are" + poundRupees);
                break;
            case -1:
            case 6:
                break menu;
            default:
                System.out.println("You must enter an option between 1 and 6!");

        }
    }
    input.close();
    exchange.close();
}
}
```